# Make reputation a function of answer/question score

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I'm not sure whether it's technically possible to do.

Problem: let a question get $20$ downvotes and $5$ upvotes. The question's score is $-15$, while the asker's reputation increases by $10$. Doesn't make much sense.

Another example: someone asked a terrible question, got $-5$, fixed the question. The question is still not that good, but not really that bad. Now people disagree with the question score and upvote it back to $0$. Result: the asker got $40$ reputation.

**Solution:** Make reputation a function of a question/answer score. Namely:
$$reputation = \begin{cases}
score * 10 & \text{if } score \ge 0\\
score * 2 & \text{if } score < 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: In practice such questions are rare, so it doesn't seem worth the effort to implement a more sophisticated scoring mechanism.

Comment: Thinking about this, I guess you are right. I did see similar situations, but not that often.

Comment: SO/SE was designed to reward good behaviour, less so to punish bad behaviour. Also, esp. on techy/sciencey sotes we don't usually expect much controversy about how good a post is.